# Timezone issue with cron inside a Debian Docker container

Tags: debian, cron, docker, timezone

Here is my Dockerfile (or at least the interesting part):

```
FROM debian:7
MAINTAINER pjb <pjb@example.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential ntp cron

ADD config/job /etc/cron.d/job
ADD config/cron /etc/default/cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/job

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I use this command to run the container:

```
docker run -d --restart=always -e "TZ=Europe/Paris" -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro --name=mycontainer pjb/repo
```

When I enter the container (`docker exec -it mycontainer bash`) all looks good to me:

/etc/cron.d/job:

```
* * * * * root /bin/date >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

/etc/default/cron:

```
READ_ENV="yes"
TZ="Europe/Paris"
```

/etc/timezone:

```
Europe/Paris
```

And `/bin/date` gives me the correct time.

But the date I get inside /var/log/cron.log is UTC time. It should be UTC+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the timezone directly **in my application** (run by cron), and it works as expected.

```
ENV['TZ'] = 'Europe/Paris'
```